# Android Studio: Error (2,0) Could not find method android() for arguments

Tags: android

Android Studio: Error (2,0) Could not find method android() for arguments [build_a4vgo3afez72iz8asoewhe39c$_run_closure1@7748caff] on root project '[ProjectName]' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

I am a new programmer just starting out, however I've had a problem with Android Studio in that my project will not successfully build. The response each build is the one stated above.

Anything you spot that can be the source of the problem? (Thanks in advance)

My **Module** app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'java'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.rookr.scientificcalculator"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
```

My **Top-end** app:

```
android {

    buildscript {

        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `android` from the Top-level `build.gradle`.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: I know, I forgot to take it out. Just wanted to see whether it would make a difference. Any other problems?

Comment: @E.Andersson i've edited the answer. And the question. Now it is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Remove android from top build

File should be start with buildscript